# What is a better phrase that will inform the user about app autostart?

Tags: usability, notification, mobile-application

What is a better phrase that will inform a user about an app autostart after power connected:

- "App will run automatically on power connected"
- "App will start autommatically when power connected"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Name of App* will launch when phone is connected to power.

With this description, the user will have more context as to what app will launch when the phone is connected to a power source. Also by saying that the app will launch when the phone is connect to a power source prevents the statement from reading like the app has to be connected to a power source instead of the phone.